# Need Help Diagnosing why Kivy Android App Crashes on Launch

Tags: android, android-studio, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I've developed a KivyMD app which runs fine on my Windows machine.  However, my company has locked down all my USB ports, so I'm not able to "deploy" the app for testing with Buildozer.  Instead, I'm using Android Studio to emulate Android.  I'm able to install my APK file (produced with Buildozer) on the virtual device, but when I launch the app I only see a Kivy splash screen which says "Loading..." for a second and then it crashes.

Android Studio provides the following log, but as far as I can tell it offers no clue to what the problem is.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.facefinder, PID: 3493
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.facefinder/com.example.facefinder.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4205)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4237)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.example.facefinder.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1446)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7939)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4237) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

What can I do to diagnose my problem?  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for taking the time to help me.  I've edited my post so the log is more readable.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array` Well somewhere in your code you try o use the length of an array (probably in a loop) but you have no array. Your array pointer/variable is null.

Comment: your log does not include the python log !!
its hard to spot the traceback 
will be better to use `adb logcat *:S python:D` to debug kivy app

Comment: @HussamF.Alkdary Thanks for taking a look at my issue.  As I stated in my original post, this log was produced by Android Studio because I don't have a means of deploying my Kivy app with Buildozer.  So I am attempting to run the APK file that Buildozer produced on an emulated Android device and I got the log posted above.  What I've learned is that Kivy development for Android must be done with deployment with Buildozer.  Otherwise you're flying blind.  This is hard for me since I am using WSL, which does not support attaching USB devices.

Comment: in this case your log is `java EXCEPTION` I can not help with that since I'm not java dev so to solve this you need java dev tell you why this happened and kivy dev to tell you how you can fix it in your code as suggestion you can add `java` hashtag to your question